# Google Maps V2 doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

Anybody here, who knows, why this not works?:

Manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MyAPIKey" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

implement in my xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's     
AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You  
must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"   
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have the meta-data in my manifest, but i'm getting the error. Why?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your manifest file-

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat itself clearly saying that:

**You must have the following declaration within the application element:**

```
 <meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"   
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```